# pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/green '

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, errors, color, pgfkeys

I want to set the fill-color of a rectangle depending on a number stored in a counter. This is my try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\background}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\fill [#1]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (.7cm,-.7cm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-.7cm,.7cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcounter{test}
\setcounter{test}{1}
\newcommand{\chooseColor}{\ifnum\thetest=1 green \else red \fi}

\begin{document}
\background{green} % everything is good
\newpage
\background{\chooseColor} % throwing the error shown below
\end{document}
```

Whilst `\background{green}` yields what I'm looking for, `\background{\chooseColor}` throws the following Error:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/green ' and I am going to
 ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

I conclude from the error, that `\background{\chooseColor}` has been evaluated to 'green' correctly, however I get that error message. Is there anything I missed out on this one? I will be glad for every help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that you define

```
\newcommand{\chooseColor}{\ifnum\thetest=1 green \else red \fi}
```

Hence, you assign `\chooseColor` with `green`  or `red`  with a trailing space. This space is taken over to Ti*k*Z, but `green`  (with a space) is not a valid color to Ti*k*Z (nor is `red` ).

Remove the spaces and it should work:

```
\newcommand{\chooseColor}{\ifnum\thetest=1 green\else red\fi}
```

Comment: This is totally not a beginner's mistake by the way! It happens to me all the time =)

Comment: Thank you very much, sometimes the answer is both too tricky and simple at the same time!

Answer (score 4):

Another way to remove the spaces is to use the `/.expanded` key handler.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\background}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\fill [#1]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (.7cm,-.7cm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-.7cm,.7cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcounter{test}
\setcounter{test}{1}
\newcommand{\chooseColor}{\ifnum\thetest=1 green \else red \fi}

\begin{document}
\background{green} % everything is good
\newpage
\background{color/.expanded=\chooseColor} % throwing the error shown below
\end{document}
```